# Image styles are not generated in Docker for Windows

Tags: 8, media, .htaccess, files

When I open in browser http://localhost:1567/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/2017-10/478069720_1384178114_4.jpg, I see 404.

The "original" images are uploaded successfully, and the website works without any problems. Only the image styles are not generated.

My environment:

- Drupal 8. Patched with https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/944582-124.patch, see the issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/944582.
- I use the [php:7.0-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/89894ff2da4da406d52931f1acebf9a2f349a898/7.0/jessie/apache/Dockerfile) image.
- Permissions for `sites/default/files` is 755, owner is root.
- `tmp` has 777, root.

I debugged: there is no request to index.php.
When I remove the `SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove ...` in /sites/default/files/.htaccess, everything works. But I do not want to remove these security headers.

FYI: in Docker for Windows everything is executed as root and default permissions are 755. See [Official docker for windows documentation about file permissions.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#can-i-change-permissions-on-shared-volumes-for-container-specific-deployment-requirements)

**Current workaround**

Custom Dockerfile with the next lines at the end:

```
# Docker works with mounted directories as user with uid 1000.
# A www-data should be 1000 to prevent problems with permissions in /sites/default/files directory.
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && adduser dev --disabled-password --gecos "" && usermod -aG www-data dev
```

Comment: As you are inside your local dev environment I'ld say you don't have to be too concerned about security.